# MySQL can I in a join calculate and show the results

Tags: mysql, view, calculated-columns

I have 2 tables in the first I define the equipment possible like fire hydrant or fire alarm system, all of theese are to check within a certain time, in this table I have the name of theese equipments and the time within they are to chec, in the second table I have the date when the last chec was I want create a View List but that contains the information, when the next chec is to realize,
Like this

```
Create View listafacilitymanagemen AS
SELECT DISTINCT ID, tipo, posicion, checeo, checeo + checeointerval, 
JOIN ID, tipo, checeointerval
FROM hotel.facilitymanagemen_equipo
ORDER BY checeo + checeointerval;
```

My database is very big and I don't want this in another column in the the table "facilitymanagement".

Comment: You need a joining condition between the tables, otherwise you get a full cross product.

Comment: You can't have `JOIN` before `FROM`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.`JOIN` has to be followed by a table name, but `ID`, `tipo`, and `checeointerval` are columns, not tables.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired result.

Comment: Thats right theese are columns

Comment: And ID in the table "facility_equipmen" is there a primary key and in facilitymanagement defined as a foreign key. The table names are named in the select and the join order.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're the right columns. You join with tables, not columns.

Comment: `SELECT columns FROM tablename JOIN table2name ON col1 = col2 ...`

Comment: Oh yes Barman I forgot the where order

Comment: I corrected my query

Comment: Create View listafacilitymanagemen AS
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, tipo, posicion, checeo + checeointerval, 
    JOIN ID_equipo, tipo, checeo on tiponr = ID_equipo
    FROM hotel.facilitymanagemen_equipo
    ORDER BY checeo + chequeointerval;

Comment: Don't put it in a comment, edit the question.

Comment: You still have `JOIN` wrong!

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on SQL JOIN.

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM facilitymanagemen_equipo AS e JOIN facilitymanagement AS m ON e.id = m.id_equipo`

Comment: Hello Barman, I work without a surface of programming I designe the tables in Excelt, as soon as I can program I will publish the working code. I just wanted to know if in a view list one can calculate and show the result.

Comment: A view can do almost anything an ordinary query can do, including calculations. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html for the restrictions.

Comment: One time is a typo, multiple times is just not reading. It's barmar, not barman. If you type `@` before a name, you get automatic completion and it will spell it correctly.

Comment: Oh Barmar, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I trust very much in w3school, there I found this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp.

```
CREATE VIEW TABLE facilitymanagement
SELECT m.ID, 
m.tipo, 
e.tipo,
e.ID,
m.posicio,
m.checeo,
m.checeo + e.checeointerval,
m.checeocontrollado,
m.checeooficial,
m.checeooficial + e.checeooficialinterval,
m.checeooficialcontrollado,
m.controllero,
e.checeointerval,
e.checeooficialinterval
FROM hotel.facilitymanagemen (m)
INNER JOIN hotel.facilitymanagement_equipment (e)
ON m.tipo = e.ID
ORDER BY m.checeooficial + e.checeooficialinterval;
```

I'm a german and by law we are to chec the equipments in a building that has to do with fire to chec by a specialist and a responsable authority, moreover we have for everything an insurance and if the interval are exceeded they don't pay, so this View list is very important, I added some columne aboveall "checeooficial" and this columne with the interval give the ORDER BY criteria.

If my code works I cannot try.

Answer (score 0):

Because I have 2 data bases I precise from whitch one I want the data in the FROM and the INNER JOIN clause it is the data base "hotel".

Answer (score 0):

I added a WHERE claus to filter the lines, so the VIEW TABLE contains only the data after the actual system-date and I ORDERed DESC; so the most urget equipment apears first.

```
CREATE VIEW TABLE facilitymanagement AS
SELECT m.ID, 
m.tipo, 
e.tipo,
e.ID,
m.posicio,
m.checeo,
m.checeo + e.checeointerval,
m.checeocontrollado,
m.checeooficial,
m.checeooficial + e.checeooficialinterval,
m.checeooficialcontrollado,
m.controllero,
e.checeointerval,
e.checeooficialinterval
FROM hotel.facilitymanagemen (m)
INNER JOIN hotel.facilitymanagement_equipment (e)
ON m.tipo = e.ID
WHERE m.checeooficial + e.checeooficialinterval > NOW()
ORDER BY m.checeooficial + e.checeooficialinterval DESC;
```

Instead of NOW() better would be to call the CURDATE()-function.